# Add border to custom CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

How can I add border to `UICollectionView`'s cells which uses a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`? When I override `UICollectionView`'s flow layout, cell borders are "removed". how can I set borders properly?
Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

I'm not sure how you want your border to look like, but whenever I need a quick border around a view, I usually use the following:

```
var view = UIView(frame: frame)
view.layer.borderWidth = 1
view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
```

**Update  Swift 3**

```
view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

You can either probably apply this to your collection view cell or create a custom class that sets these values after initialization.

Either that, or you can set the cell size so that spaces between cells serve as borders and set `minimumLineSpacing` and `minimumInteritemSpacing` in your custom flow layout implementation.

Comment: Simple and worked great.  You can just add it to a cell and there you go.